# JSON to UITableView Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to read a file `countries.json` and the display this data in a `UITableView`. By searching stackOverFlow I did as they said in there:

```
-(void)loadJSON{

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    countries = (NSArray *)jsonObject;

    NSLog(@"Count of Countries: %ld",[countries count]);

}
```

This `NSLog` prints `248` which I think is the correct value and I'm assuming that it is reading it correctly. And the two compulsory methods of `UITableView` are also done:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [countries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CountryTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

But when I run this file I get this error:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe903e7fb30
2015-04-27 16:51:14.561 appMeNo[10192:1073720] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe903e7fb30'
```

I've followed a lot of solution but nothing is working. I'm using `tabViewController` in this app. Which I think is not causing problem.

**UPDATE**
 I'm using this [Github Library](https://github.com/mledoze/countries) OR for a more clear image of the file here is the exact file which I copied into my project [countries.json](https://github.com/mledoze/countries/blob/master/countries.json)

Comment: Add your countries.json file log for better understand your problem

Comment: where are you calling loadJSON function

Comment: You need to show your JSON for us to figure out what's going on

Comment: Please can you show me your response?

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya check my update.
@vijeesh yes I'm calling this function in `viewDidLoad`
@Chackle check my update.

Comment: @TalhaCh try like this [[[countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] objectForKey:@"common"];

Comment: You have not filtered dictionary content properly...use  countries = [jsonObject allValues]; This will return all values for dictionary. While displaying content on cell label use [[[countries objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] objectForKey:@"common"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a call of `isEqualToString` on an `NSDictionary` object instead of `NSString`. Once you show your JSON data it'll give me a better idea of what exactly is going wrong.

Make sure you're understanding your JSON data structure correctly before parsing it. My guess is you're accessing it incorrectly after `loadJSON` is called.

EDIT:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] objectForKey:@"common"];
```

Comment: Yes I also figured it out but I've check every single `.m` and `.h` files there is no `isEqualToString`. I've updated my question you can check my .`json` file

Answer (score 1):

countries array has `NSDictionary` type object so for example you have country_name at indexpath
try this

```
cell.textLabel.text = [countries [indexPath.row][@"country_name"]];
```

Comment: doing this generates an in line error that subscript requires size of interface... `cell.textLabel.text = [countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row[@"Afghanistan"]];`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] objectForKey:@"common"];
```

I hope this code useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are making a call `isEqualToString`. Now the source string is not valid at that time. its been pointing to Dictionary object.

Check the reference of the string variables which are genrating the call of method `isEqualToString`.

Comment: Yes I also figured it out but I've check every single `.m` and `.h` files there is no `isEqualToString`